# How to hide edittext cursor when user click anywhere else outside edittext or anywhere else on screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want to hide the blinking cursor in edittext when user clicks anywhere else on the screen. From the various existing Stack Overflow threads, I have tried almost everything but nothing seems to be working in my case.

I am using the following code to achieve this:

```
searchText.setOnFocusChangeListener(object : View.OnFocusChangeListener {

            override fun onFocusChange(view: View, hasFocus: Boolean) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    searchText.setCursorVisible(false)
//                    saveCancelBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    searchText.setCursorVisible(true)
//                    saveCancelBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

But it's not working out, I have tried by adding focus,etc in XML but they are also not working.

Comment: I have a bad solution to offer, `requestFocus` of some other element if nothing else helps.

Comment: please read again the question title

Comment: Ah I assumed you knew how to set an `onClick` listener on the background. `onFocusChange` is not gonna help here because nothing else can take the focus, I presume

Comment: how would clicklistener will help here?

Comment: set it on the background and trigger the behavior there. So when the user clicks on anything OTHER than the EditText, focus some other element. That was my idea

Comment: so you mean to say i should check with every element ? if that's not that editext then hide its cursor?